# list not recoginized farther down in code

Tags: python

I have some code that loads a list(data) from a .json file. It then loads first element of the data into a QTcomboBox. That all works fine. However when I go to compare the data to what I selected from the combo Box the data list is empty. What's going on. This works perfectly when I load the data using csv. Why is the data variable empty in this part of the code?
I am just learning so  I can't figure this one out

```
import os
import shutil
import sys
import csv
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication,QMessageBox, 
QInputDialog
from PyConWinPy import *
import pyperclip
import subprocess
from easygui import *
import json

filenamePos = 
r"C:\Users\MJBmsi\Documents\A_python\QtPyConverter\mjbpos.txt"  # 
desktop
filename = 
r"C:\Users\MJBmsi\Documents\A_python\QtPyConverter\pyCode.json"  
# desktop

data = []
dataPos = []
data2 = []

class MyForm(QDialog):
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_mDialog() #change the MDiolod to form name
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.comboBox.activated.connect(self.com_index)
        self.ui.comboBox.addItem("Select Py")
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.but_Cmd)
        self.ui.butAdd.clicked.connect(self.butAdd_click)
        self.ui.butDelete.clicked.connect(self.butDelete_click)
        self.ui.butBackup.clicked.connect(self.butBackup_click)
        self.ui.butRestore.clicked.connect(self.butRestore_click)
        self.ui.butSP.clicked.connect(self.butSP_click)
        self.show()
        #revised the window title to show date and time
        title = "Python Convert -Code Inc. by eeMBee" 
        self.setWindowTitle(title)

        #open position file and move dialog to that position
        with open(filenamePos) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            rownum = 0
                for row in reader:
                dataPos.append(row)
                rownum += 1
        f.close()
        tl = str(dataPos[0])
        Lt = int(tl[2: -2])
        pt = str(dataPos[1])
        Tp = int(pt[2: -2])
        self.move(Lt, Tp)
   
# open data file and load array
    with open(filename, 'r') as fd:
        data = json.load(fd)
        global mjb
        mjb = len(data)
    fd.close()
    
    # load the comboBox - #################THIS WORKS FIN
    for x in range(mjb):
        mss = data[x][0]
        self.ui.comboBox.addItem(mss)
         
# when combobox selection is made load the path and filename
def com_index(self):
            fn = self.ui.comboBox.currentText()
            global pro
            pro = fn
            for z in range(mjb):
                mss = data[z][0]  ##data is empty at this stage         and 
                if fn == mss:     ##also anywhere farther down in code 
                    global ind 
                    ind = z
                    self.ui.label.setText(data[z][1])
                    global pth
                    pth = data[z][2]
                    self.ui.myStatus.setText(pth)
                    #print(pth)
                 
# opens the command prompt and loads the 2 commands into the clipboard       
def but_Cmd(self):
            s = data[ind][1]
            sb = "pyuic5 -x " + s + ".ui -o " + s + ".py"
            ms = pth + " & " + sb
            pyperclip.copy(ms)
            proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe /k')
            sys.exit()
           # print(pth)

#Starts the process to add new projects to the file
def butAdd_click(self):
        newName, ok = QInputDialog.getText(
        self, "Code Inc. by eeMBee", "Enter the new PROJECT name")
        print(newName)
          
        newFl, ok = QInputDialog.getText(
        self, "Code Inc. by eeMBee", "Enter the new FILE name") 
        newFile = newFl + "Py"
        #print(newFile)
    
        newPath = diropenbox() 
    #myNewFile =  newName + "," + newFile + "," + "cd " + newPath 
        myNewFile =  '"' + newName + '"' + "," + '"' + newFile + '",' + '"' + "cd " +  newPath + '"'
        #print(myNewFile)
    
        with open(filename, "a") as f:
            f.write(myNewFile)
            f.write('\n')
        f.close()
        self.ui.myStatus.setText("The new Project is saved to the data file")
 

#opens notepad for deletion # show a Continue/Cancel dialog
def butDelete_click(self):
        button = QMessageBox.question(
            self, "eeMBee Code Inc.", "Shall I delete the Project " + pro + "?"
        )
        if button == QMessageBox.Yes:
             with open(filename, 'r') as fd:
                data = json.load(fd)
                data[ind][0] = "DELETE" 
                for i in range(mjb):
                    if data[i][0] != "DELETE":
                        data2.append(data[i])
                        
             with open(filename, 'w') as fd:
                json.dump(data2, fd)
                
             msg = "the Project " + pro + " was Deleted"
             self.ui.myStatus.setText(msg)
                
        else:
            msg = "Nothing was Deleted"
            self.ui.myStatus.setText(msg)
    
    
#backs up the data file
def butBackup_click(self):
        sor = filename
        des = r"C:\Users\MJBmsi\Documents\A_python\QtPyConverter\pyCode.bak" 
        shutil.copy(sor, des)
        self.ui.myStatus.setText("The data file is backed up")
 
 
# restores the data from the backup file 
def butRestore_click(self):
        des = filename
        sor = r"C:\Users\MJBmsi\Documents\A_python\QtPyConverter\pyCode.bak" 
        shutil.copy(sor, des)
        self.ui.myStatus.setText("The data file is restored")


# saves the position of the form in the window
def butSP_click(self):
        # Get the geometry of the dialog
        geom = self.geometry ()
        # Get the x and y coordinates of the top-left corner x = left, y = top
        x = geom.x ()
        y = geom.y ()
        lines = [str(x), str(y)]
        with open(filenamePos, 'w') as f:
            for line in lines:
                f.write(line)
                f.write('\n')
        f.close()
```

#base code_ required for form to appear
if **name** == "**main**":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MyForm()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

Comment: Please post the code that comes before this. It looks like from where your code starts is actually part of a different function. That could explain alot.

Comment: Added full code

Comment: Having global variables is generally pretty bad, but having them with infuriatingly opaque names like `data`. It's doubly frustrating when you have `data2` as well for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in `MyForm` you are reading data and saving it to a variable local to `MyFormn.__init__` called `data` (that is **NOT** the global `data`).

To explain:

```py
data = []
def read_data():
    data = [1 ,2 ,3]
    print(data)

read_data()
print(data)
```

This will print `[1, 2, 3]` the first time (when called inside the `read_data` function and `[]` the second time.
If you want to use the global `data` you need to explicitly tell it to python:

```py
...

def read_data():
    global data
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Once you explained why the error was happening, I tried several things and ended up opening the file and loading the data before loading the form and now all is cool. Thanks again Matteo